# Add icon to AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

```
private void firstTimeRan() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("How to use the app: ")
                .setMessage("BLANK")
                
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create().show();
    }
```

How do I add an icon to the dialog?

When trying `.setIcon`, I don't know what value to put in. Thanks!

Comment: `.setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)` where your_icon is a a name of drawable of your icon, for example it might be your_icon.png in your res/drawable folder

Comment: did you solve it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Confirm Action");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to go back?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Perform the desired action when the user confirms
            // For example, you can call super.onBackPressed() to go back
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing or handle the cancel action here
        }
    });

    // Set an icon for the AlertDialog
    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

    builder.show();
}
```

this is what you are looking for >>

```
     builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
```